# How to count elements inside a time window in Apache beam, and emit the data when the count reach some threshold?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to count elements per key from unbounded source (I am using Pub/Sub for my source) within a time window, and emit the count result when it reach some threshold. For example, I want to count the elements within 10 minutes fixed time window, and emit the results to another Pub/Sub when the count is > 5.

```
    transformation = (p
                    | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription))
                    | 'parse' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
                    | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(600))
                    | 'count' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerKey()
                    | 'filter' >> beam.Filter(lambda data: data['count'] > 5))
    transformation | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic)
```

However, the results that written to the Pub/Sub seems to be delayed, and from my estimation, the result emitted after the window time expired. What are the additional window option/code do I need to emit the result immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see in [the documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#event-time-triggers) that you can add trigger on window.

Go to the section 9.3 and you have the definition of the `AfterCount` trigger that emit the data every each "count completed".

I never wrote this in Python (only in Java), but the code should be like this

```
    transformation = (p
                    | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription))
                    | 'parse' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
                    | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(600),
                        trigger=AfterCount(5))
                    | 'count' >> beam.combiners.Count.PerKey()
                    | 'filter' >> beam.Filter(lambda data: data['count'] > 5))
    transformation | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic)
```

To be sure to process all the elements (if you have less than 5 element at the end of the window) you need to build a composite trigger, like this

```
trigger=Repeatedly(
        AfterAny(AfterCount(5), AfterProcessingTime(10 * 60))),
```